# Want to make a pop up message for the Error on Android

Tags: android, error-handling, popup, toast

This is the method that i want to add popup message. If the result set contain "404" i want to display a message. I can't use Toast here because this is not have written on any Activity Context.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // To make a popup notification when it is a Not Found Location
    if(result.contains("404")){
        return;
    }

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (baseFragment != null) {
        if (isMainTask) {
            baseFragment.onTaskFinished(result);
        } else {
            baseFragment.onSubTaskFinished(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Use an AlertDialog developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html‎

Comment: pass the context to the non activity class constructor and use the same to display toast

Comment: Use "new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Title ").setMessage("error: here").show();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating any sort of ErrorDialog/Dialog or PopupWindow you need the activity Context. PFB a sample code for returning an alert dialog:

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(baseFragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .setTitle("TITLE OF YOUR ALERT DIALOG")
            .setMessage(“MESSAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW”)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("BUTTON NAME",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int whichButton) {
                    removeDialog(The id of the managed dialog);


                    //TASK YOU WANT TO PERFORM
                                      finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("BUTTON NAME",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int whichButton) {
                    removeDialog(The id of the managed dialog);
                    finish();
                }
            }).create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Activity context using `baseFragment.getActivity();` or application context using `baseFragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext()` and display Toast using application context or You can also display alert dialog using activity context. 
Note: for displaying dialog you must use activity context otherwise it will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a Dialog you need to have a reference to the context. You can pass to the AsyncTask a reference to the context through the class constructor or a setter method before you call the AsyncTask's execute method.